# Why is my session unset/ destroy not working?

Tags: php

On my page I have a session being created which can be accessed and called fine usually. However, I am adding a logout button which links to `logout.php` which only contains the lines

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

Noting out the `session_destroy`, I've noticed that there is no error, but nothing happens to the current session. However, `session_destroy` is giving the following error. Similar questions show that this is because people have not called session start, but the session has been started in my `login.php`

[image: error]

Comment: You have some output before calling session_*() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got error in your logout.php page. You wrote only two lines but try to add one line at the top of the page in your PHP scope.

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

It will work...!!!

Comment: seems to work, but im curious why a session_start() has to be there when its already started in the main page?

Comment: As my point of view you started session in login page and now you want to logout from application then you call logout.php in your case then logout.php could not understand actually session start or not ? That's why you need to start session again in your logout page..!!!